# How to get dependent value from dropdownlist in razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Suppose I have the following object:

```
public class CountryAndState
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<string> States { get; set; }
}
```

This object is populated in my view, like the following:

```
<select id="CountryDropdown" name="CountrySelector">
@foreach (CountryAndState cas in Model.CountryAndState())
{
    <option value="@cas.country">@cas.country</option>
}
</select>
```

The thing is, that I want to populate a second `dropdownlist` with states depending on which country is selected in the above `dropdownlist`.

However, I can't seem to access the ID of this `dropdownlist` in order to get the dependency in my razor code for the next dropdown of states.

- therefore, how do I add this dependency and dynamically populate my states dropdown based on the selected country in the first one?

Answer (score 0):

```js
use the jquery min
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#CountryDropdown').change(function () {

var txt = $("#CountryDropdown option:selected").text();

var v = $("#CountryDropdown").val();
 here add the dropdown of state

})
});
```